# System Storage Taking Up Way Too Much Space in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, diskspace

My mac is sending me the frequent alert of low disk space. When I am checking the system storage then it's showing 170+gb is occupied by the system. I am not sure where is my space is getting used?

I tried a few cleaner tools also but couldn't get help much.

Please help to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: It took me quite a while to find the redundant files on ~/Library/Caches as mentioned on other guidelines, but it wasn't very helpful. Until I got to know DaisyDisk from this answer: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253616229?answerId=256789176022#256789176022. I then deleted a significant amount of extra space. (I'm not DaisyDisk's seller or employees)

Answer (score 8):

After doing research over various forums of mac's and StackExchange I figured out that it's mostly because of the following reasons.

1. Log files (Might be crash log files/docker files)
2. Your email messages stored in outlook (in my case it was almost ~20 GB)
3. Logs related to cores when a system restarts (~ 10 GB)
4. Docker Images (This had ~70 GB in my case).
5. Your nonsystem documents/downloads/itunes

So the question is how to find what all things are unnecessary and safe to delete? These system files are not visible directly.

I tried using a few tools like cleanmymac etc but all were paid so I couldn't get help much there.

To clean up your non-system unnecessary files, you can directly take the help of the storage management tool of mac. You just have to click on optimize storage and it will show all the non-system files.

[image]

To cleanup unnecessary system files, use below command

```
sudo find -x / -type f -size +10G
```

This command will give you all the files occupying more than 10 GB. You can analyze the files and delete them [image]as necessary.

The highlighted cores are nothing but the state files of your mac to reboot from last state when your mac restarts so it's safe to delete.

Next step is to delete a hidden tmp folder 
[image]

It will show the size as 0 bytes because your user won't have permission to read it. But will be occupying a hell amount of space. So delete it by giving root permission.

Now, Look if there are any docker images present in your system. Clean them all (Docker.raw).
[image]

Using all these steps I was able to clean almost 100+ GB.

Comment: I can't see those hidden tmp folder in my mac

Comment: is it safe to delete the hidden tmp folder?

Comment: yes, docker was 64gigs with a tiny little app. ridiculous

Answer (score -1):

Recently found that this issue was caused by a memory leak in one of the Java applications I was running. I had to start the Activity Monitor, searching for Java processes and Force Quit them. Rinse and repeat every time my space runs out. Also fix your code where you can to get rid of memory leaks.

Comment: this article discusses about storage, but not memory space.